# Managed (.NET) library with HTML Tidy-like functionality?

Tags: .net, html-parsing, htmltidy

Is there an HTML cleaner for .NET that can parse HTML and (for instance) convert it to a more machine friendly format such as [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML)?

I've tried the HTML Agility Pack, but that fails to correctly parse even [fairly](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/28204) [simple](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/29218) examples.

To give an example of HTML that should be parsed correctly:

```
<html><title>test</title>
<body>
    <ul><li>TestElem1
        <li>TestElem2
        <li>TestElem3 List:
            <ul><li>Nested1
                <li>Nested2</li>
                <li>Nested3
            </ul>
        <li>TestElem4
    </ul>
    <p>paragraph 1
    <p>paragraph 2
    <p>paragraph 3
</body></html>
```

`li` tags don't need to be closed ([see specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/lists.html#h-10.2)), and [neither do `P` tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1). In other words, the above sample should be parsed as:

```
<html><title>test</title>
<body>
    <ul><li>TestElem1</li>
        <li>TestElem2</li>
        <li>TestElem3 List:
            <ul><li>Nested1</li>
                <li>Nested2</li>
                <li>Nested3</li>
            </ul></li>
        <li>TestElem4</li>
    </ul>
    <p>paragraph 1</p>
    <p>paragraph 2</p>
    <p>paragraph 3</p>
</body></html>
```

Since the aim is to use the library on various machines, it's a big disadvantage to need to fall back to native code (such as a wrapper around [HTML Tidy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Tidy)) which would require extra deployment hassle and sacrifice platform independence, not to mention being impossible in sandboxed scenarios.

Any suggestions?
To recap, I'm looking for:

- An HTML cleaner ala HTML Tidy
- Must be able to deal with real world HTML, not just XHTML, at the very least correctly reading valid HTML 4
- Must be able to convert to a more easily processable XML format
- Should be a purely managed application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [TidyManaged](https://github.com/markbeaton/TidyManaged).​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I haven't seen TidyManaged, if I ever need something similar again, I'll take a peek.  However, your timing is uncanny, as I *did* write a patch to add support for optional end tags to HTML agility pack just two weeks ago: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/29218 - I'm hoping they'll integrate it and that'll be that.

Comment: It looks like TidyManaged is a wrapper rather than a port; that's slightly unhandy as it won't work in things like silverlight, and it requires you know the platform you'll be executing on at compile-time.  Still, for many uses those restrictions aren't an issue.

Comment: I've listed a few more Implementations of HTML TidyLib for .Net at my blog http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2011/06/08/implementations-of-html-tidylib-for-.net.aspx

Comment: :-) Nice summary.  It *is* a tricky problem;  I'm not quite sure I fully trust Html Agility Pack.  There's also the Majestic 12 parser which sounds robust, but it's really more like a tokenizer - it's not going to fix or hide things like missing end tags.  And there's lots of Tidy's, but even tidy isn't perfect; if the html is malformed (not just wrong nesting), tidy may refuse to process the input entirely, leaving it tricky to use without human interaction (it's fine for a website editor, less so for a search engine).